# C void Pointer on mainframe

Tags: c, pointers, void, hexdump

I'm currently working on modifying a dump program, but I can't figure out how to properly navigate with a void pointer. Below is the function that I'm working in, and the instruction that I'm trying to execute. I've tried casting mem to a struct, but I'm not sure of the sytnax and I keep getting an error. For the code below, the specific error I'm getting is:

```
       47       |   mem = mem->tcbtio                                    
===========> .........a..............................................
*=ERROR===========> a - CCN3122 Expecting pointer to struct or union.
```

Here is my function:

```
void hexdump(void *mem, unsigned int len)
{                                        
   mem = mem->tcbtio;                     
   ...
}
```

Here are my struct defintions:

```
struct psa {           
 char psastuff[540];   
 struct tcb *psatold;  
        char filler[4];
 struct ascb *psaaold; 

};                     

struct tcb {           
 struct prb *tcbrb;    
 char tcbstuff[8];     
 struct tiot *tcbtio;  
};           

struct tiot {     
 char tiocnjob[8];
 char tiocpstn[8];
 char tiocjstn[8];
};
```

I need to keep it as a void pointer, as I need to cast it to char and int later on in the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as you are expecting to find a `tcb` struct, starting at the address pointed by mem, but the aim of the code is obscure and the question not clear.

If this is really the case, you can try this:

```
   mem = ((struct tcb *)mem)->tcbtio;
```

Comment: On next usage (dereference) of `mem` it will again be a `void` pointer only.

Comment: @MadHatter as it should be if he's not going to declare a new pointer, since he's loading a `struct tiot *` not a `struct tcb*`.

Comment: @jthill : Right! I didn't noticed that. I corrected my answer too. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dereference a `void` pointer. You can think it this way if you have a `void` pointer, how will compiler know what type of address it is holding. And by doing `mem = mem->tcbtio` how much offset it has to make.

Modify your function as:

```
void hexdump(void *mem, unsigned int len)
{
   struct tcbtio *mem2;
   mem2 = ((struct tcb*) mem) -> tcbtio;
   ...
   // Use mem2 later
}
```